count distinct records from jsonb column
I have a column stored as jsonb which is an array of number. Values look like this

I'd like to count the total distinct values from this column. I can get the distinct values like below
SELECT DISTINCT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(aimjoined) AS aims FROM mytable;

I can't figure out how to count the total number of occurences for each of the unique values.

First flatten the table using a lateral join and then do a trivial group by.
SELECT aims::numeric, count(*)
FROM mytable, 
lateral jsonb_array_elements(aimjoined) AS aims
group by aims;


This is great.. I ended up finding a solution with the query below as well. It seems to perform about 35% faster. Not sure exactly why
SELECT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(aimjoined),COUNT(*) as count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DISTINCT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(aimjoined)
ORDER BY count DESC

I ended up also finding the solution below. It seems to perform slightly faster than that by @Stefanov.sm.
SELECT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(aimjoined),COUNT(*) as count 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY DISTINCT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(aimjoined) 
ORDER BY count DESC

